# How to experiment with rspec from within irb

Tags: rspec, mocking, irb

For example, I want to say b = double("book") in irb and play with the result.

In irb if I say

```
require 'rspec'
b = double("book")
```

I get an error. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play around with RSpec test doubles in `irb` by [requiring `"rspec/mocks/standalone"`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-2/docs/outside-rspec/standalone):

```
$ irb
> require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'
> b = double("book")
  =>  #<RSpec::Mocks::Mock:0x3fd88d0157e8 @name="book">
```

Comment: Great tip! What other .../standalone options are there? Any?

Comment: As far as I know, it's only mocks, but you can stub methods and set message expectations on your mock objects, which is pretty handy.  If you find anything interesting out, please update this thread!

Comment: The other idea I got which is quite nice is to call irb or pry from inside the test that you are trying fix. That will allow you to have a 100% correct state in which to experiment.